# $0$ is an interior point of $\overline{T(S_1)}$, where $T(S_1)$ is the closure of $T(S_1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

If $B$ and $B′$ be Banach spaces and $T$ be a continuous linear Transformation from $B$ onto $B′$.  Let $S_1$ be an open sphere of radius $1$ in $B$.  Then show that $0$ is an interior point of $\overline{T(S_1)}$, where $T(S_1)$ is the closure of $T(S_1)$

I have a feeling that open mapping theorem will be used here, but I am not able to understand how?

Comment: Is $S_1$ supposed to be an open *ball* centered around $0$? (note a sphere is the boundary of a ball, it usually doesn't make much sense talking about open spheres) if it's not centered around $0$ you can easily come up with examples where $0$ isn't even in $\overline{T(S_1)}$

Comment: @MorA. Yes. It is centered around $0$).

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=\mathbb{R}$, $B'=\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $T(x)=(x,0)$. Then the closure of the $T(S_1)$ is $[0,1]\times \{0\}$. But 0 is not interior to this.